# box2d Stop sprite at the end of platform

Tags: box2d

Sorry for my English,

I am using BOX2D and I have a tile which is a Fixture, and a player which is a DynamicBody.
When I click the direction on the mouse I am calling the method setLinearVelocity, and the player begins to move left or right accordingly something like this:

__*_*__*_*__*_**0****_*__*_*__*_*_**

Where 0 = player, and _ = the tile.

I want to know how can I check if the player is in the end of the platform, i.e:

__*_*____0

and stop it from moving or whatever.

I tried using the Contact Listener's endContact event, in which I called applyImpulse(), which pulled the object away, but it did not work so well.

I also thought of getting the length of the Fixture and then by calculating the player position relativity to the fixture I could have got the end point, when they both touch, but I did not find "size"  for the Fixture.

Does someone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use contact listener. Just do some geometry calculations. First obtain circle fixture size or polygon fixture vertices and detect if the player is on the edge of the tile like this. For obtaining above mentioned info do this:

```
for (b2Fixture* fixture = body->GetFixtureList(); fixture; fixture = fixture->GetNext())
{
    b2Shape::Type shapeType = fixture->GetType();
    if ( shapeType == b2Shape::e_circle )
    {
        b2CircleShape* circleShape = (b2CircleShape*)fixture->GetShape();
        auto radus = circleShape->m_radius;
    }
    else if ( shapeType == b2Shape::e_polygon )
    {
        b2PolygonShape* polygonShape = (b2PolygonShape*)fixture->GetShape();
        auto verices = polygonShape->m_vertices;
    }
}
```